# jQuery and IE not playing nice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this section of code:

```
function createDownload() {
        var category, format, specification, download;

        $('#submitform').click(function() { 
            category = $('#cate').val(); 
            format = $('#form').val(); 
            specification = $('#spec').val(); 

            if (category == "NULL" || format == "NULL" || specification == "NULL") { 
                alert("Please select all options.");
                return false;
            } else {
                download = "pdfs/"+specification+format+category+".pdf"; 
                window.open(download);
            }
        });
    }
```

Now... In Internet Explorer it says there is an "Error on the page" - `Message: 'return' statement outside of function` and I have to click the button again.

In Firefox, Chrome and Safari - I have to click the button twice to get the PDF to appear... (and no errors)...

Now why could that be?!

As per request - My Form declaration:
`<form method="post" action="javascript: return false;" onSubmit="createDownload();">`

Comment: Problems with IE… Where have I heard that before?

Comment: might not be relevant, but post your code that calls the `createDownload` function as well.

Comment: is `createDownload()` being called? The `click` event won't be bound until `createDownload` is called. Also could you give a more verbose error statement from IE? What version of IE? Do you have IE developer tools (IE8+)? Which line is this outlying return statement on?

Comment: Please post the HTML code for the particular form tag in which this submit button is residing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `action='javascript: return false;'` and remove the `onsubmit`.  It should become `action='javascript: createDownload();'`

Answer (score 2):

```
<form method="post" action="javascript: return false;" onSubmit="createDownload();">
```

Since you are using return false not in a function it is throwing the error. You will have to put that in an anynymous function.

Something like

```
<form method="post" action="javascript: function() {return false;}" onSubmit="createDownload();">
```

will work

Better to bind the event `.submit()` for the form

```
<form method="post" id="frm1"></form>

$("#frm1").submit(function(){
    // your code
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the return.  It seems you don't even need it, and if that's really the cause of the problem then what's the point keeping it there?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove the `action` from the form - it serves no purpose here. Also, assuming `#submitForm` refers to the form submit button, your first click will attach the click handler and the second click will actually call it. Instead, remove the onsubmit attribute and just attach the handler in the usual way to either the button click or form submit event, being sure to cancel the event in either case:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#submitform').click(function() {
    // or: $('#formID').submit(function() {
        var category, format, specification, download;

        category = $('#cate').val(); 
        format = $('#form').val(); 
        specification = $('#spec').val(); 

        if (category == "NULL" || format == "NULL" || specification == "NULL") { 
            alert("Please select all options.");
        } else {
            download = "pdfs/"+specification+format+category+".pdf"; 
            window.open(download);
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```